# element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated - Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Following is the html

```
<div id="form1:customertype" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" style="width: 165px;">
   <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
      <select id="form1:customertype_input" name="form1:customertype_input" tabindex="-1">
         <option value="S">Staff</option>
         <option value="C">Customer</option>
         <option value="N">New To Bank</option></select></div>
  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input id="form1:customertype_focus" name="form1:customertype_focus" type="text" readonly="readonly"></div>
  <label id="form1:customertype_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all" style="width: 149px;">Staff</label>
  <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right ui-state-hover"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"></span></div></div>
```

The stylesheet of class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" is

```
ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
      border: 0;
      clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
      height: 0px;
      margin: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 0px;
   }
```

Following is my code

```
    WebElement customerType = driver.findElement(By.id("form1:customertype_input"));
    Select select = new Select(customerType);
    select.selectByVisibleText("New To Bank");
```

When I try to select "New to Bank" from the dropdown I get exception
element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated - Selenium webdriver

I have tried WebDriverWait technique but of no use, any ideas ?

Comment: does the dropdown opens?

Comment: Probably the select drop down is wrapped. This usually happens when creating a jazzy drop down. check if it is actually hidden.

Comment: yeah manually the dropdown opens but not from code. The dropdown is visually visible on the page.

Comment: try to access it via parent div: WebElement customerType = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='form1:customertype']//select[@id='form1:customertype_input'])

Comment: Tried this but the result is same. interesting part is that it doesnt throw an exception until this line select.selectByVisibleText("New To Bank");

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the text for that option is actually visible before you attempt to select it. Try selecting by value instead.

```
WebElement customerType = driver.findElement(By.id("form1:customertype_input"));
Select select = new Select(customerType);
select.selectByValue("N");
```

You may need to actually click the selector before being able to select an option, though.

```
WebElement customerType = driver.findElement(By.id("form1:customertype_input"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(customerType));
customerType.click();

Select select = new Select(customerType);
select.selectByValue("N");
```

Answer (score 0):

try performing click on *customerType* before you create object of **Select**

Comment: same result :( I get the exception on this line
select.selectByVisibleText("New To Bank");

Comment: use some other identifier to click like index of the content, put all the option tags in a list and select by index number 2 to select _New To Bank_ option

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a work around to solve my problem but I am not happy with this. anyways what I did is focused on the div element that controls the dropdown by clicking it and and then sending down arrows keys twice followed by enter key. This selects my desired option. I used the following method

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and after hours I realized the browser was trying to click in a element before the page load.

So I create a sleep to solved the problem:

```
sleep(1)
```

**P.S.** - This is a solution that I really don't like.
I'm just pointing you the reason for that.
The best you can do is to check the page that you have the problem and try to optimize the load time.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem. I have tried many methods.
Finally, the following python code solved the error.
I use javascript code to make the element visible before selecting the option.

```py
css = 'select#state' # css selector of the element
js = """const data_options = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('{css}'));
        data_options.forEach(a=>{{a.style='display:block;';}});""".format(css=css)
self.driver.execute_script(js)
```

Maybe it's helpful for you!